# How can I get the attribute values in component HTML?

Tags: angular

I am having table where on click I am making sorting.I have directive attached to it and I am changing dynamically the attribute `data-order="desc"`  on click so it could be `asc` or `desc`. It is changed on table header click.

```html
  <th scope="col" [appSort]="dataSource$" (sortObservableEmitter)="test($event)" data-order="desc" data-name="firstname">first name
       
 </th>
```

Now i want to show arrows on my table - when it is ascending i want to show the arrow up font awesome icon. When `data-order` is changed to `desc` i want to show the arrow down font icon.

But when I try for example

```html
 <th scope="col" [appSort]="dataSource$" (sortObservableEmitter)="test($event)" data-order="desc" data-name="firstname">first name
        <i *ngIf="data-order == 'asc'" class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
 </th>
```

it is not working.

How can I get here in my `ngIf` directive the value of `data-order`?

Comment: Check this out: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax. See if you can assign a template variable to `th` and then see if you can access the attributes it has and refer to it in the `*ngIf`.

Comment: Why not solving this using css to rotate the arrow? You can use these selector: 
th[data-order='desc'] i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a directive you can indicate the "exportAs", see e.g. [this link](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26)

So if your directive is like

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[appSort]',
 exportAs: 'appSort' //<--add this line
})
....
//I imagine you has a variable sortDirection
sortDirection:string=null;
```

you can access to the variables public (by defect in Angular all the variables are public) of the directive using a template reference variable

If I imagine that has a variable that is called e.g. `sortDirection` you can write

```
<th scope="col" [appSort]="dataSource$" #colFirstName="appSort"...>first name
        <i *ngIf="colFirstName.sortDirection == 'asc'" class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
 </th>
```

NOTE: Instead two *ngIf, I prefer use ngClass in the way

```
        <i [ngClass]="colFirstName.sortDirection=='asc'?'fas fa-arrow-up':
                      colFirstName.sortDirection=='desc'?'fas fa-arrow-down':null"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you.It is working. I am glad that i will accept your answer

Comment: Btw how can i remove the previous arrow - for example i click on first name i get the up arrow, after that i click on the last name i get there up arrow too, but i need to 'remove' the previous maked arrow on the first name column

Comment: @Petar, I don't know about your directive, check what value and what variable change if no sort direction is selected